# Why do I get a message saying 1.not.found.as.a.resource?

Tags: itext, itextpdf

What might cause

```
new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 11f, Font.BOLD)
```

or

```
BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, 'Cp1252', BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)
```

to start returning the following??

```
com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: No message found for 1.not.found.as.resource
```

itext 5.5.6 jar on Max OSX 10.10

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not using the "pre-canned" jar, but that you have created your own jar. That self-made jar only contains the Java class files. It misses resources such as the language (`.lng`) and the Adobe Font Metrics (`.afm`) files.

If the above assumption is wrong, then at least this is right:

- Instead of the actual error message, you get the *key* to an error message that is stored in a `.lng` file: `1.not.found.as.resource`. This key is used to find the actual error message in the language of your OS (English, Dutch and Portuguese are supported; the default is English).
- The actual error message (should `en.lng` be found) would have been: *"Helvetica not found as a resource"* (the `1` in `1.not.found.as.resource` is a placeholder). This message tells you that the file `Helvetica.afm` can't be found. This file contains the metrics of every glyph in the font Helvetica (regular). Without those metrics, you can't create a proper PDF.

This explains *what* happens. Your question doesn't contain sufficient information to explain *why* it happens. All of this shouldn't be a problem when using the correct jar with a JDK that knows how to read resources from a jar. The fact that you write *"What might cause* ... **to start** *returning the following"* indicates that it has worked for you before. Think of what you have changed between the last time it worked and the first time it stopped working (e.g. changing the OS, changing the JVM,...). That will probably be the culprit.

Comment: A: not true - this is happening with 5.5.4 and 5.5.5 and 5.5.6 all downloaded from source forge this afternoon.

Comment: Check what's inside. If the `.lng` and `.afm` files are there, then the problem is not an iText problem, but a problem of your JDK that refuses to read those files. Error messaging and AFM functionality has been working correctly since their very inception. In this case, iText is not the culprit. My first guess would be: look at the JVM.

Comment: You can verify my allegation by trying those jars on another operating system (Linux, Windows,...) using the official JDK from Oracle. The fact that you ask "What might cause ... **to start** returning the following" indicates that it has worked before for you, which should also point in the direction of something you changed (like the OS or the JVM).